# Transpiling React code, but leave ES6 alone

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, webpack, gulp, babeljs

I'm writing a Chrome Extension using ES6/React/Redux babel and Gulp.

I was using babel presets es2015, stage-2 and react.

Then I realized as I'm only targeting Chrome I could get rid of the es2015/estage-2 stage as it's supported by Chrome.

So the first I tried was to get the .babelrc and remove the references to es2015 and stage-2.

Not so fast... Before running *webpack* gulp script fails to run.
What I tried first was to make only the gulp file ES5 compatible.

Then I got errors of spread operators not being supported, so I re-added "stage-2" loader.

Then I got errors in different modules:

```
> WARNING in ./background/src/index.html Module parse failed:
> /my_path/my_project/src/index.html Unexpected token (1:0) You may need
> an appropriate loader to handle this file type. SyntaxError:
> Unexpected token (1:0)
>     at Parser.pp$4.raise (/my_path/my_project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
```

To help to understand how my code is structured, it's in 3 main folders:
**background**, **content** and **popup**. Each one representing a Chrome environment.
For each one, I have a separated webpack.config.js file, similar to this one: https://pastebin.com/hseVyQaw
Gulp then calls webpack for each config file and generated the bundle output file for each one, during the build process.

There's a way to make Gulp/Webpack works with ES6 syntax, while not transpiling it for the deployment?
What's the best approach for this issue?

Gulp version

```
> [17:32:27] Requiring external module babel-register 
> [17:32:27]CLI version 3.9.1 
> [17:32:27] Local version 3.9.1
```

Webpack version: 1.14.0

**UPDATE**
After adding html-loader as suggested by @Michael Jungo it seems to run fine, but it gives me a warning, not sure how bad is to ignore it:

```
WARNING in ./background/src/index.js
Critical dependencies:
17:29-52 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./background/src/index.js 17:29-52
```

**UPDATE 2**
Oh, Chrome is complaining about modules syntax of my extension, but based on what I read it's suppose to be supported:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not related to babel or any ES6 features. You're trying to import the HTML file `./background/src/index.html` but in the config you've posted, there is no rule for `.html` that could handle these files, therefore webpack tells you that you might need an appropriate loader for this file type.

You can use the [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) and add the following rule to your `loaders` array:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html-loader'
}
```

As for your babel config, it should work as you wanted. Keep in mind if you're using ES modules (`import/export`) you would still need to transpile them or switch to [webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) which supports them out of the box. Also UglifyJs doesn't understand ES6 syntax, if you want to uglify ES6 you have to use an alternative like [babili](https://github.com/babel/babili) with the [babili-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babili-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.
I was thinking about migrate to webpack2, but as it's still in beta I was not sure.

Comment: It has been released for a long time now, the first release [`v2.2.0`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.2.0) was in January, and the current version is [`v2.3.3`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.3.3) which was released 4 days ago.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try.
So I tried just adding the html template... and running only webpack (no gulp), and it fails to understand the spread operators... so I re-added "stage-2" only, and it seems to works, but it gives me a warning: https://pastebin.com/m5yPUFYA
and the built file is still in ES5.

I'll give a try to webpack2 and I hope I can get it working there.